# web sub application design

Tags: asp.net, iis

If a current web site needs to be changed to a sub application within a parent web site is there design changes that must be applied or amendments that must be made to make the site work as a sub application?

Typically we use IIS and we may need to convert some web sites\applications to sub applications and I my concern is if there any issues that need addressing in the design\architecture to ensure there are no problems with it working as a sub application?

Also, what are the implications of creating a virtual directory into a sub application - what issues need to be addressed in that scenario?  For example what about paths in a sub application created from a virtual directory

I have created a few trial sub applications from sub directories and virtual directories (where virtual directory physical folder is within the parent site), but my concern is the design in converting a current web site into a sub application.  I reviewed the Microsoft website on differences on sites, sub directories, sub applications and virtual directories. However, this does not discuss the issues with converting a current website to a sub applicationand ASP.NET

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis#applications The meaning behind "In the case of managed code applications, make sure to associate your application together with an application pool that is running the .NET Framework version that your application requires" is that your ASP.NET web app can only be deployed as IIS applications, not virtual directories. People deploy such for decades. You just need to test it out and resolve bugs in your own code.

Comment: You can create a sub application from IIS under the parent website, this is very easy, it is worth noting that you must have enough permissions to access iis.

Comment: @samwu Thanks for feedback.  yes, I have created a few trial sub applications and viewed them in browser with default.aspx etc but my question is - are there any considerations around it being a sub application that needs to be built into the design?

Comment: I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, my suggestion is that you can try it first, if you get any problems, please come back to discuss.